# Symfony: Ordered one-to-many relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two separate entities that I want to link by a one-to-many relationship. But I want this relationship to be ordered, meaning every time I call on the first entity, the elements of the second entity come in a pre-ordered way. I cannot use 'order by' calls because this order has nothing to do with the fields of the second entity. I thought about having one field of the first entity be an array of entities, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that either..

**EDIT**

So far I have something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FusionDesign\BlogBundle\Entity\Element", mappedBy="page")
 */
private $elements;
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FusionDesign\BlogBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="elements")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $page;
```

I'm aware that I can put "ORDER BY whatever ASC" somewhere in there but that orders according to a column in Element, and that's not what I need, because Element entities and Page entities would never be persisted at the same time, nor by the same process. What I want to do is constructing a basic CMS where the user could generate new pages. First choose the kind of elements a page could potentially have (like header image, banner, title, and so on) and persist Element entities with fields describing the html, routing and controller content according to those choices. Then, when a new page is created, give the user the choice to order those potential elements at will, and bind Element entities following an order that reflects the layout desired.

I thought about having something like this

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="structure", type="array")
 */
private $structure;
```

Where the array stores Element entities but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: How should be ordered these entities? By some field of what?

Comment: can you please write down what you coded ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the `orderBy` attribute in doctrine's mapping configuration for the relation.

YAML Mapping Example:

```
'Example\Entity\Article':
  # [..]
  oneToMany:
    images:
      targetEntity: 'Example\Entity\Article\Image\ArticleImage'
      mappedBy: 'article'
      orderBy:   # <--- here
        position: 'ASC'
```

Comment: I cannot have the order be determined by a column in the second entity. Isn't there a way to define a more flexible order by some other mean, or should I rely on a third entity